# How to find Term frequency of a particular sets of tags in a document

Tags: python, annotations, tf-idf

How can I find the frequency of each of these annotations; author, year, lang and also, the frequencies of occurence of their unigrams, bi-grams, trigrams...ngrams i.e.

```
"<author>James Parker</author><year>2008</year><lang>English</lang>"
"<author>Van Wie</author><year>2002</year>"
"<year>2012</year><lang>English</lang>"
"<year>2002</year><lang>French</lang>"


 file = 'file.csv'
 df = pd.read_csv(file)               
 lines = df['query']
 for line in lines:    

     #calculate tag frequency

  #calculate frequencies of unigram, bigrams, trigrams,....ngram tags 

> author: 3, year: 4, lang: 3

  trigram: author, year, lang : 1
  bigram: author, year: 1
  bigram: year, lang: 2
```

Comment: What is the upper bound on n? If there is one that will affect the kind of algorithm you might want to use.

Comment: for this example its 3: author, lang and year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you only count 1 ngram per line, so the line

```
"<author>James Parker</author><year>2008</year><lang>English</lang>"
```

has a trigram and 3 unigrams. You don't need all combinations for each line.

The simplest way to count this is to just use a dictionary accessed by the tag or tuple to store the count. That gives you a single pass and should scale well with the number of input lines. I use a regular expression to pull out the first of each tag (this means the input has to be well formed) and then just index into the counter by tag name and then by the n-tuple formed by the set of tag names.

```
import collections
import re

string = """<author>James Parker</author><year>2008</year><lang>English</lang>
<author>Van Wie</author><year>2002</year>
<year>2012</year><lang>English</lang>
<year>2002</year><lang>French</lang>"""

strings = string.split("\n")
counter = collections.Counter()

tag_re = "\<[^/\>]*\>"
for s in strings:
    tags = re.findall(tag_re, s)
    tags.sort()
    # use name directly
    for tag in tags:
        counter[tag] += 1
    # use set for ngram
    ngram = tuple(tags)
    counter[ngram] += 1

print counter
```

This prints:

```
Counter({'<year>': 4, '<lang>': 3, '<author>': 2, ('<year>', '<lang>'): 2, ('<author>', '<year>'): 1, ('<author>', '<year>', '<lang>'): 1})
```

Comment: how can I extend the regex pattern to cover n = 5

Comment: As written it should work for any value of n. It just pulls out the first tag of each open/close pair. Do you have a sample input that it fails on?

Comment: Oh yes! it works. I made a silly mistake putitng `string.split()` in a wrong place. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But I tried using pandas `import pandas as pd    file = 'C:/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
strings = df['columnA']` and commented out `strings.split()`, tag returned empty array after applying the regex pattern